# Is there way to return a response, then a function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a switch case which returns different functions depending on the condition, I have an issue in navigating from the previous function to the next one after sending an xml response

So far i have put a check on xml response after it is done then you can return to another function.

```
public function userStart(Request $request, $progress)
    {
        \Log::info('User Starts here');

        switch ($progress) {

            case 1:
                $progress = 1;
                return $this->stepCellphone($request, $progress);

                break;

            case 2:

                return $this->stepOmang($request, $progress);

                break;

            case 3:

                return $this->stepFirstName($request, $progress);

                break;
        }

    } 

 public function stepCellphone(Request $request, $progress)
    {

        if ($progress = 1) {

            Log::info($progress); // 2
            \Log::info('At stepCellphone');


            $config = [
                'template' => '<ussd></ussd>',
                'rowName' => 'name',
            ];

            $text = $request->get('msg'); // get text from msg

            return response()->xml($data, 200, $config);

        }
        $progress = 2;
        return $this->userStart($request, $progress);

    }

    public function stepOmang(Request $request, $progress)
    {

        $progress = 2; 

        Log::info($progress); // LOG the progress of the user as the current tep
        \Log::info('At stepOmang');
        $config = [
            'template' => '<ussd></ussd>',
            'rowName' => 'name',
        ];
        $text = $request->get('msg'); // get text from msg

        if ($text != null) {
            return response()->xml($data, 200, $config);
        }
        $progress= 3
        return $this->userStart($request, $progress);
    }
```

I expect after the first XMl response to move to another, Its a step by step process,After the user enters their cellphone, it should update the progress value return the userStart() and go to the next CASE.

Comment: You can use only one `return` from function. What you are trying to achieve? It is not fully clear

Comment: After making a xml reponse, i want to proceed to a function

Comment: return response()->xml($data, 200, $config); Will break all you next code and will return HTTP response. So you should return response only once after all work already done. 

I will suggest to move response to userStart() function

Comment: Yeah same thing I noticed, so you're suggestion is to move the xml response of userStart() function, how would I move to the next function from there?

Comment: userStart(Request $request, $progress)
  {
        \Log::info('User Starts here');

        switch ($progress) {
            case 1:
                Log::info($request); // 2
                \Log::info('At stepCellphone');

                $data = [
                    'type' => '2',
                    'msg' => "Enter CellPhone Number",
                ];
                $config = [
                    'template' => '<ussd></ussd>',
                    'rowName' => 'name',
                ];
                return response()->xml($data, 200, $config);
                break;

Comment: This is for validation?

Comment: Seems you are validating the Request right?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know how to move to next function after the request?

Comment: These 3 functions are controller actions?

Comment: Yes, ``` return response()->xml($data, 200, $config)
                ->withCallback($this->userStart($request, $progress));
I am trying to get the call back response , set progress to 2 and return to the userStart() t go to the second case

Comment: Are you trying to stream one part of the XML to the user at a time?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see you are setting `$progress = 2` after you return XML response. in this way the `$progress = 2` wouldn't execute. So how can we expect to move to another function, while `$progress = 2` has not been set  yet?

Also you should save `$progress` somewhere in database in order to retrieve the previous `$progress` from the database. So that every time the user send a request you know what state the user is and what state the user successfully passed.

This means every time that the `$progress` is going to change you should update its value in database (Which you are not doing this in your code).

Other than mentioned problems. Your code actually not right. It will face error. `$data` is not defined and `$progress` is not being saved in database. However the place of change is wrong too. it is not clear how (or where) do you retrieve `$progress` value.

for example take a look at the `stepCellphone` method

```
public function stepCellphone(Request $request, $progress)
{

    if ($progress = 1) {

        Log::info($progress); // 2
        \Log::info('At stepCellphone');


        $config = [
            'template' => '<ussd></ussd>',
            'rowName' => 'name',
        ];

        $text = $request->get('msg'); // get text from msg

        //if this method is going to run when $progress = 1 the function is done here. nothing will execute after
        //Also $data is not defined
        //you should change the $progress value here

        return response()->xml($data, 200, $config);

    }
    //if this method is going to run when $progress = 1 how do you even think the code might reach to this line?
    $progress = 2;
    //even if the code reach this line, why $progress is not being saved anywhere!
    //
    return $this->userStart($request, $progress);

}
```

I suggest rethinking for better algorithm.

1. check for user state is the first thing you should do.
2. doing stuff according to the state
3. save the next state that supposed to be run in database related to the user
4. send response to user which include instruction so user knows what to do.

I personally save the class name and the next method in database and act based on my saved data.

Comment: How do you suggest we move to another function after the XML response?

Comment: before sending response, set `$progress = 2` save it in database. Next response to the user, this response should include asking user for next input. user will response for next input, the next input will be send to you by user. at this time you check for $progress value in database. so that you know what state the user is in. now you run `userStart`.

Comment: I already have a model and database which will store the user Array from XML responses, that logic is complete, the only difficult part is after respone()->xml is done, because It ignores all code which is supposed to move to the next function

Comment: Buddy this application is running on Users Cellphone.. and functionality is handled by Laravel

Comment: when you return something how do you expect the code go to next line! it is basic php!
when user send next input to you every variable you are setting in the php will reset and won't exist anymore including `$progress`. laravel or not laravel, this is not different

Comment: I am aware of that, Because we're sending a response can we do something after the user has input the data?..

Comment: yes we can. you should rethink your algorithm. Algorithm for ussd robots or similar robots is as I said. Because there is no form or view to indicate user position. So we never know what state is the user if we don't save the user state. First, you check the state of the user. is the user first time user or not! is he in the middle of something?